# Running script with an exe on computer shutdown

Tags: script, batch-file, shutdown, group-policy

I asked this same question on stack overflow for mistake.

I have a computer that does not turn on if it is on expanded mode connected to a TV. Just black screen and no signs of life.

The thing i want to do is have a script that switches the Display to internal before shutting down. I tried with a script that has **C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /internal** and shutdown signal. This won't work because the person operating the computer can't really click on the script.

What i wanted to do is put it as a machine shutdown script. I tried these: Script with **C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /internal** and parameter **/internal** and also just adding a script with Name **C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe** and parameter **/C C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\internal.bat** but still no luck.

This should work right? it only works when ending user session, so only when configured by user and not machine.

The machine is on Windows 10.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ModeratorImpersonator
I already had that, just didn't express myself well.
Here is what i have and does not currently work: [http://imgur.com/a/0mO4K](http://imgur.com/a/0mO4K)
I didn't try putting it in a new folder on C.

The thing is, this works well if i apply it to user instead of machine.. but with user i won't be able to cover the shutdown part.

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator no luck :(. If i run the script it actually opens that little window as if you did **WINDOWS + P**.. can it be that? It opens this panel, switches to internal and closes.  I see on event viewer a warning saying that the visualization controller stopped responding.

I also added **pause** to the bat file but no command prompt shows when i shutdown. Will search if there is a way to change the display without using DIsplaySwitch.exe.

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator So when i type in DisplaySwitch and after that press **UP**,**UP** and *ENTER* it gives me the result i want, so internal screen. If you could do this for me it would be great.
I will also need to do the same with pressing two down arrows, but i think i can copy what you did and make that little change.
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

With a batch script you can execute [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) by creating a dynamic VBS script and then have [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html) execute it when needed. The line `WshShell.SendKeys "{UP}"` in the below example batch script presses the up arrow but replacing that as `WshShell.SendKeys {"DOWN}"` will press the down arrow instead.

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO ON

DisplaySwitch

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%temp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{UP}"                             >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{UP}"                             >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

EXIT /B
```

---

### Further Resources

- [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)
- [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)

Comment: You doing all the work and i can't do the simple thing. So the script is running, i just added the "{ESCAPE}" key so it closes the window. But if i put it as a .bat file it still doesn't run on shutdown. The entry is created on regedit and everything but still doesn't work. The batch is on C:\ because it could be permissions but still nothing. I'll test if it actually starts running, if it does the .vbs file will be created on temp.

Comment: Ok, this is getting strange. I also tried by task schedule when event 1074 is triggered and it says that the action was initiated and finished. I'm not really seeing why it isn't working anymore. Here are the images, they are in portuguese but it basically shows task schedule success and error on event viewer as i still had the batch on shutdown. [http://imgur.com/a/xubZN](http://imgur.com/a/xubZN)

Comment: I'm doing this on a machine that is not on domain :)
I'll be trying all of the above in a few minutes. I was doing all by machine because the script i had in the beginning would not work on logoff.

Comment: Ok, no luck at all. I will try on the target computer and see if it goes well, maybe it can work.. who knows. On logoff or shutdown it doesn't work, it works well on logon though.
I'll keep you updated. If it doesn't work i'll try to just have a shortcut with a power off button to the script.. maybe the person operating it will like the idea of just double clicking to turn off.
Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoSantos Have you had any success with this by chance yet? I tested as a shutdown script having a simple batch process that logs to a log file with `>> logfile`, and it appears to echo the lines to the log file. However, when I try to get it to run an action interactively so it runs so the end-user that's logged on can see what's it's doing e.g. the `sendkeys()` methods, it doesn't interact. I'm going to do further testing with a logoff script rather than shutdown and see what my results are are soon as I get a chance. Give me an update if you've gotten any new findings on the matter.

Comment: Sorry, had a quick vacation ;)
No updates.. in no way i can make it run on shutdown or on logoff. Even on logoff it immediately logs off and no action is taken.
Ye i see, when i was running the script on shutdown it even created the log file but no action was taken.
I think i really have to go with the shutdown button on this case :(

Comment: @JoãoSantos try to add it in the shutdown gpo or try to add shutdown command into the script so when you double click the script it will shutdown the computer and run the script or use it as a task scheduler with the shutdown option inside the script